# Messages are abusive or marked as spam - Facebook Chat [Developers]

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xmppframework, facebook-chat

I'm developing an iOS application that allows a user to login in the Facebook and then send messages to his friends using the Facebook Chat API.

To connect my Facebook account, i'm using **xmppframework** (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework). The connection is well established and I can send messages to my friends. However, when the conversation is reopened (Facebook web site, messenger) the message is no longer available and a new message is shown: "This message is no longer available because it was identified as abusive or marked as spam".

I've no idea that what's happening. I already tried to check the permissions, track the authentication flow and I found nothing anormal.

Anybody knows what I have to do to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved! I changed the Sandbox mode to off and the messages aren't identified as spam anymore.